# how to detect data type and read data from pptx slide

Tags: python, file, python-pptx

[sample ppt slide.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYKgT.png)

I have to read pptx file.
while reding it, i am going to extract some data but not all data from slides.
find slide sample. i am able to read all data except {1,2,3} options data.
i wish to read it also

here is code.

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation(path_to_presentation)

# text_runs will be populated with a list of strings,
# one for each text run in presentation
text_runs = []

for slide in prs.slides:
   for shape in slide.shapes:
     if not shape.has_text_frame:
        continue
   for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
       for run in paragraph.runs:
           text_runs.append(run.text)
```

Comment: Are you sure those are in slides.shapes, and are you sure they *have* text_frames? Maybe you can make a list of *all* objects on the slide and use `dir()` to see what types they are and what properties they have. Do a full inventory of what's on the slide. Since you only posted a `png` it's hard to help further.

Comment: Yes , i checked some data is not coming in slides.shapes, thats why i am unable to see it where that data goes in in which type

Comment: I'm not familliar with pypptx but reading [this](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) I wonder if it can only read the objects that it is able to generate. It doesn't say it can read *any* file. It seems more for automatic ppt generation. [This](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#community-guide) sends me to [here](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/community/support.html) which shows a google mail list for questions and getting help - I'd look into that if you haven't already. Also [this](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues).

Answer (score 0):

All items on a slide are a shape of one sort or another. The only exception is a background image.

There *is* however the business of shapes being "inherited" from the slide layout. Items in the slide layout (such as a logo for example) will *visually* appear on the slide as rendered by PowerPoint, but will not be contained in the XML for a slide and will not appear in slide.shapes.

Another thing to be aware of is that PowerPoint breaks up runs of text for all sorts of reasons, even when they have exactly the same formatting. You can't be sure it will keep a logically single run in one piece. So depending on the form of the data you're looking for, you may want to just access the paragraph.text directly and parse things out from there.

Of course if a shape is an image (of a 1. or 2. for example), they'll appear visually as text but will not have a text frame or any text.